# RTF to Wiki Converter?

Tags: wiki, markup, rtf

I would like to convert 100+ RTF files to Wiki Markup, but I can only find "Wiki to RTF" converters on the web and even here on StackOverflow.

I only need **RTF --> Wiki Markup**

Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: Which markup flavour exactly are you looking for? Wikis do use different ones.

Answer (score 2):

I simply asked the *wrong* question.

Did some research and found out that there is no Converter which converts **RTF** directly to a "**Wiki** format".

The "better" question: *Save Word file as Wiki markup*.

There are some approaches using **Microsoft Word** to save as .txt (Wiki markup):

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Word2MediaWikiPlus
- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12298
- http://techwiki.openstructs.org/index.php/Wiki_converters
- http://www.consumingexperience.com/2008/03/convert-word-doc-or-webpage-to-wiki.html

Good luck!

Comment: Links are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

It may be unwieldy with hundreds of files, but I have used wikEd to convert RTF and Word formatted text to wiki markup.

Wikedbox is a usable implementation of wikEd without installing it:
http://www.appropedia.org/index.php?title=Appropedia:Wikedbox&action=edit

'''Wikedbox HELPS YOU CONVERT HTML (WEB FORMATTED CONTENT) TO MEDIAWIKI.'''. More instructions at [[Appropedia:WikEd]].

INSTRUCTIONS:

1. If you're not in edit mode, click the "edit" tab now.
2. Paste in your content.
3. Click the red [W] to convert. (Middle row, second block from the left.)
4. Your text is ready to be copied and used on your wiki page. (You may need to make further corrections.)
5. '''DO NOT SAVE THIS PAGE'''. (You'll be blocked from doing so, anyway, unless you're an admin.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/):

```
pandoc -s README -o example.rtf
```

This will convert your file to Markdown. I don't know which Wiki you want to use and If it understands Markdown, but I thinl you can also convert it to MediaWiki or other output formats (see the Pandoc User manual).

Comment: Thank you for hint. Even pandoc seems to be a great converter it is not what I am looking for. I like to convert **from** RTF **to** Wiki markup. pandoc only supports RTF as output format but I need it as input format.

Comment: Ops sorry, you are right. Maybe you can write a script for OpenOffice or something like this.